# iPhone to iPhone networking

Tags: iphone

I am interested in developing an iPhone application that creates ad-hoc networks between iPhones.

Is such an application feasible?

I am a novice with iPhone development, so I apologise in advance for my naiivety.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In iPhone OS 3.0, Bluetooth is used to create an ad-hoc network and has been developed for this purpose.

Here is some documentation.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html

On a side note, there are some games that use the current access point and scan the subnet that they are on and find other listening clients. Then they create a game that way.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but since I just researched a similar topic, I wanted to share the results in case it's helpful to someone who searches for this in the future.

Newer iOS versions include [Game Kit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html), a set of APIs allowing developers to create peer-to-peer networking systems over WiFi *or* Bluetooth.  This appears to be exactly what the poster is requesting.

Comment: +1 @mhucka; however, @Ben was asking about ad-hoc networks between iphones, it is not the same because with the Game Kit you make the connection with an existing network(not ad-hoc).